# Fazer teste em janela anônima no SeleniumWebdriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando fazer com que o Selenium execute os testes em janela privativa do Firefox, mas a execução continua sendo feita em janela padrão. Está faltando algo?

```
private IWebDriver driver;
        public IDictionary<string, object> vars { get; private set; }
        private IJavaScriptExecutor js;
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
            firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            vars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
        [TearDown]
        protected void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        [Test]
        public void teste()
        {
        xxxx
        xxxxx
        xxxxx
        }
```

Comment: tenta adicionar o argumento  `firefoxProfile.addArguments("-private");`

Comment: 'FirefoxProfile' does not contain a definition for 'addArguments' and no accessible extension method 'addArguments' accepting a first argument of type 'FirefoxProfile' could be found